# Number format of ValueBox<Double>

Tags: java, html, gwt

I found a strange bug. I have a class derived from `ValueBox<Double>` to display numbers. I add some styling to it to make it prettier using `setStyleName();`

It has worked well for some time now, but just now I noticed a strange bug. If I set a value greater than 999 the display is blanked.
I figured out that if I remove my call `this.getElement().setAttribute("type", "number");` everything works as it should.
I suspect the problem is that values over 999 is displayed as 1.000 and that is not acceptable as a number.

It work in Firefox, but fails in Chrome/Chromium. No wonder since Firefox ignores the type attribute anyway.

So there are two ways to solve it.

1. get it accepted as a number
2. change the formatting to leave out or change the separator

But how?

Comment: Please mention the browser with versions that you have tried with as well

Comment: It work in Firefox, but fails in Chrome/Chromium. No wonder since Firefox ignores the type attribute anyway.

Comment: Why do you use .setAttribute() at all? Why not use NumberFormat, a standard way for GWT number formatting, instead?

Comment: I want to set type=number to make a number keyboard pop-up on phones and tablets instead of the full keyboard.